# how to feed the result of a pipe chain (magrittr) to an object

Tags: r, magrittr

This is a fairly simply question. But I couldn't find the answer per google/stackexchange and looking at the documentation of magrittr.
How do you feed the result of a chain of functions which are connected via %>% to create a vector?

what I saw most people do is:

```
a <-
data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>%
sum()
```

but is there also a solution where I can just pipe-chain the result to feed it to an object, maybe an alias or sth of the like, somewhat like this:

```
data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>%
sum() %>%
a <- ()
```

this would help with keeping all of the code in the same logic of feeding results forward "down the pipe".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>% sum -> a
```

Comment: +1 I never thought there would be a justification for the `->`.  Now there is!

Comment: But if you just use `->` you can´t keep going with the chain: for example `data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>% sum -> a %>% exp` gives an error, you would have to use parenthesis `(data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>% sum -> a) %>% (exp)` and if one is not careful that may lead to unexpected results .

Comment: G. Grothendieck, I've tried the code above (`data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>% (sum -> a) %>% exp`), but It does not correctly assign the partial result to `a`.

Comment: (1) Its not a good idea to continue the chain. If you really want to assign a variable part way through its better to make it into two chains.   One could still write it like this: `data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>% sum -> a; a %>% exp` to avoid the problem. (2) Assigning part way through is a side effect and the functional style is to avoid side effects.

Comment: How about: `tee=function(v,n){assign(n,v,.GlobalEnv);v}` and then `d %>% whatever %>% tee("part1") %>% otherstuff $>$ tee("part2") %>% etcetc`

Comment: I think one normally wants the object to be assigned into the current environment rather than the global environment in order to be able to use it in functions.

Comment: Bizarre `a` is half the answer to life, the universe, and everything. `a * 2 == 42`.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like so:

```
data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>%  
sum %>%  
assign(x="a",value=.,pos=1)
```

A couple of things to note:

You can use "." to tell `magrittr` which argument the object being brought forward belongs in. By default it is the first, but here I use the `.` to indicate that I want it in the second `value` argument instead.

Second I had to use the `pos=1` argument to make the assignment in the global environment.

Comment: You really shouldn't use assign for just about anything.  It's bad coding practice.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName Can you expand on that? What is the danger here?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `<<-` operator:

```
data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>%
  sum() %>%
  `<<-`(a,.)
```

***Edit:*** I think John Paul's is the safest suggestion, and you could keep going with the chain doing different assignments of partial results. For example:

```
data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>%  
  sum %>%  
  assign(x="a",value=., pos=1)  %>% 
  exp %>%
  assign(x="b",value=., pos=1) %>% 
  sqrt %>%
  assign(x="c", value=., pos=1)
```

This will correctly create `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: You sure it won't work with `<-` ?  Better not to use `<<-` when not strictly required.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, it won't, the `<-` operator will assign to the local environment of the function, so it will not create the variable in the global environment.

Answer (score 4):

Using pipeR's `%>>%` this should be very easy.

```
library(pipeR)
data.frame( x = c(1:3), y = (4:6)) %>>%
  sum %>>%
  (~ a)
```

The pipeR tutorial may be helpful: http://renkun.me/pipeR-tutorial/
For assignment: http://renkun.me/pipeR-tutorial/Pipe-operator/Pipe-with-assignment.html

Answer (score 3):

What I like to do (and I found this trick somewhere I can't remember) is to use `{.} -> obj` at the end of my pipe-chain. This way I can add extra steps to the end of the chain by just inserting a new line, and not have to re-position to `->` assignment operator.

You can also use `(.)` isntead of `{.}` but it looks a bit, *odd*.

For example, instead of this:

```
  iris %>% 
    ddply(.(Species), summarise, 
          mean.petal = mean(Petal.Length),
          mean.sepal = mean(Sepal.Length)) -> summary
```

Do this:

```
iris %>% 
    ddply(.(Species), summarise, 
          mean.petal = mean(Petal.Length),
          mean.sepal = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
    {.} -> summary
```

It makes it easier to see where your piped data ends up. Also, while it doesn't seem like a big deal, it's easier to add another final step as you don't need to move the `->` down to a new line, just add a new line before the `{.}` and add the step.

Like so:

```
iris %>% 
    ddply(.(Species), summarise, 
          mean.petal = mean(Petal.Length),
          mean.sepal = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
    arrange(desc(mean.petal)) %>%   # just add a step here
    {.} -> summary
```

This doesn't help with saving intermediate results though. John Paul's answer to use assign() is nice, but its a bit long to type. You need to use the `.` since the data isn't the first argument, you have to put the name of the new argument in `""`'s, and specify the environment (`pos = 1`). It seems lazy on my part, but using `%>%` is about *speed*.

So I wrapped the `assign()` in a little function which speeds it up a bit:

```
keep <- function(x, name) {assign(as.character(substitute(name)), x, pos = 1)}
```

So now you can do this:

```
  keep <- function(x, name) {assign(as.character(substitute(name)), x, pos = 1)}

  iris %>% 
    ddply(.(Species), summarise, 
          mean.petal = mean(Petal.Length),
          mean.sepal = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% keep(unsorted.data) %>% # keep this step
    arrange(mean.petal) %>%
    {.} -> sorted.data

sorted.data
#     Species mean.petal mean.sepal
#1     setosa      1.462      5.006
#2 versicolor      4.260      5.936
#3  virginica      5.552      6.588

unsorted.data
#     Species mean.petal mean.sepal
#1     setosa      1.462      5.006
#2 versicolor      4.260      5.936
#3  virginica      5.552      6.588
```