# Can the use of return() after a magrittr pipeline to write an object break something?

Tags: r, tidyverse, magrittr

I often have to manually clean up entries in datasets. 
For flexibility and readability, I like to use pipes.
Sometimes I later come across another thing I need to clean up, so I keep a copy-paste'able line in my `magrittr` pipeline.

In `ggplot2`, calling an empty `theme()` at the end helps me to keep coding flexible for later additions. I never encountered problems with that and thought I could do the same with `return()` in a pipeline.

I think `return()` is not be meant to use outside functions, so: is there a conceivable way this could break my code?

I also stumbled upon `{.}` ans an alternative, but I don't really know what it does and searching info (even using advanced search on SO) is not helping.

Example:

```
starwars %<>% 
  mutate(hair_color = ifelse(name == "Captain Phasma", "blond", hair_color)) %>%
  mutate(skin_color = ifelse(name == "Captain Phasma", "fair", hair_color)) %>%
  mutate(hair_color = ifelse(name == "Zam Wesell", "blond", hair_color)) %>%
  #mutate(var = ifelse(name == "cond", "replacement", var)) %>% ### for future c/p
  return() #
```

*NB: I realise this is borderline the tag "coding-style", so I like point out I'm not interested in an opinion-based discussion but advice if this could break my code in certain circumstances. Examples where it does break code are welcome, as are alternative suggestions.*

*I think these topics/threads are related:*

- https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/32
- [Use $ dollar sign at end of of an R magrittr pipeline to return a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130776/use-dollar-sign-at-end-of-of-an-r-magrittr-pipeline-to-return-a-vector)
- [how to feed the result of a pipe chain (magrittr) to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975827/how-to-feed-the-result-of-a-pipe-chain-magrittr-to-an-object)

Comment: Well, it might break as soon as the first example in issue 32 returns a different result, i.e., the issue gets fixed. I believe `{.}` just calls the `{` function. You could probably also use `identity` instead.

Comment: for your purpose, `identity` indeed is the appropriate function rather than `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As put forward by @Roland and @RolandASc: `?identity()` is doing what I wanted. I am using it since, and haven't encountered surprises so far.

Further related discussion found over [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-put-and-at-the-end-of-lines/1831/4) at the RStudio community.